# How to convert timestamp to string in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, date, timestamp, type-conversion

I have table with timestamps in ms stored in it. I want to convert those timestamps in a human readable form.

Here is a sample output of my table:

```
SELECT date raw, strftime('%d-%m-%Y', (date/1000)) as_string
  FROM my_table

 +-----------------+--------------+
 |     raw         |  as_string   |
 +-----------------+--------------+
 |  1444687200000  |  06-47-3950  |
 +-----------------+--------------+
...               ...            ...
 +-----------------+--------------+
```

As you can see, the date as string is quite strange (`06-47-3950`).

How can I obtain `12-10-2015`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT date raw, strftime('%d-%m-%Y', datetime(date/1000, 'unixepoch')) as_string
  FROM my_table
```

You need to convert timestamp to date before.

Comment: as_string required? doesn't strftime makes it already a string? Anyway it helped me a lot, thank you!

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz The trailing `as_string` isn't a string conversion, it names the column `as_string`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert timestamp to daytime first. There was an [answer](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148564-solved-sqlite-convert-timestamps-to-date-and-time/)  on one forum. I quote it here.

> Here you are: try those queries to see why and how.
>
> `select julianday('1899-12-30 00:00:00');`
>
> -- that gives 2415018.5 (remember Julian dates start at noon)
>
> `select datetime('40660.9454658044', '+2415018 days', '+12 hours', 'localtime');`
>
> -- gets you 2011-04-28 00:41:28 (depending on your local
>   time)