# SQLite timestamp export

Tags: sqlite, datetime, export

I have a SQLite 3 database on MacOS with timestamp data (typically something like 279020203.539467).

The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) says that dates can be stored as

```
REAL - as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich
       on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
```

And it looks like this is what I've got.

I want to export this and import it into other databases.

I am assuming the timestamp datatype is not compatible between database engines, so some conversion has to happen somewhere, and I am working under the assumption that it'd be best to do that while exporting the data from the SQLite database.

But I can't figure out how to do this conversion.

I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33114190/204658) which refers to [this forum post](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148564-solved-sqlite-convert-timestamps-to-date-and-time/) which indicates that in SQLite you could do something like

```
select datetime('40660.9454658044', '+2415018 days', '+12 hours', 'localtime');
```

(Maybe 2415018 is the number of days between November 24, 4714 B.C. and some other magical date...)

However, replacing the timestamp string in this example with what I have results in null. Presumably because '279020203.539467' is some other kind of timestamp. It is also some magnitudes larger than the example.

But how to convert this to a usable date? I know it should be around 2011/2012.

Interpreting the data as an "integer" (seconds since 1970-01-01) gives 1978 so that is not correct either.

UPDATE: I've found that

```
288773834.371606 should be 2010-02-25 07.57
296636121.950064 should be 2010-05-27 08.55
```

(CET if that matters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATEDIF("2010-02-25 07.57"; "2010-05-27 08.55"; "d")
```

This gives 91 days which works out to be 7862400 seconds, almost exactly the same as the difference between the two timestamps (296636121.950064 - 288773834.371606 = 7862287.578458).

On MacOS native timestamps are seconds from 2001-01-01 (Jan 1 2001).
And

```
DATEDIF("2001-01-01 00:00"; "2010-02-25 07.57"; "d")
```

gives 3342 days which is 288748800 seconds, near, but not exactly the timestamp but that difference is caused by

- DATEDIF only caters for whole days
- CET is one hour off

Correcting for that we get around 25000 seconds more to add, which takes us almost exactly to the timestamp for 2010-02-25 07.57.

So the gist of this is that SQLite on MacOS stores timestamps as MacOS native timestamps which are seconds since start of MacOS epoch (2001-01-01 00.00). This is probably caused by the application that created the data was not using SQLite timestamps but MacOS native dates and storing them in the database as any other data.

Converting this to some other format should be trivial, either during the export, a conversion of the exported file or during imports.

Possibly it would be easiest to convert the date on export from the original database using

```
select ...
    datetime(table.timestamp_field, 'unixepoch', '+31 years')
from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The good news is:  To convert a Julian date to "regular" date format you could use `datetime(strftime('%J',jtime))`. FYI [Here's the doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for sqlite date and time functions. But there's bad news.

A [NASA Calculator](https://bowie.gsfc.nasa.gov/time/julian.html) computes the Julian date of 2010-02-25 to be 2455246. It computes the civil date of 288773834 as Sept 2, 785907 A.D. sqlite doesn't give that same result using the above notation, but it doesn't give a "date".

Even though the numbers look like Julian date notation, they are not any dates in our lifetimes.